# Leaking Method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, memory-leaks

I'm working through Stephen Kochan's Programming in Objective-C (which is to confess that I'm a complete beginner).

My current program is a fraction calculator. I have add, subtract, multiply, and divide methods. Instruments tells me they're all leaking (only a tiny bit, but it's a tiny program.)

Here's the definition of the subtraction method (the rest follow a very similar form):

```
-(Fraction *)   subtract: (Fraction *) f;
{
    Fraction    *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    int         resultNum, resultDenom;

    resultNum = numerator * f.denominator - f.numerator * denominator;
    resultDenom = denominator * f.denominator;

    [result setTo: resultNum over: resultDenom];

    return result;
    [result release];
}
```

Thoughts to plug the leak? Thanks ahead of time.

Also, I looked around for another explanations on the site, but sadly, I don't think anyone else has asked anything so basic.

Comment: Cocoa convention says that any method that returns an object that has been alloced and not released/autoreleased must have a name that starts with `new` or `create`. Otherwise, if it returns an object it should be `autorelease`d as per Bavarious's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in:

```
return result;
[result release];
```

`-release` is never sent to `result` because any statement after `return` isn’t executed. Such statements are called dead code.

You should autorelease your object, e.g.:

```
return [result autorelease];
```

Note that you should use `-autorelease` instead of `-release` because `-release` would cause the immediate deallocation of `result`, which is not what you want. An autoreleased object, on the other hand, is released at some point in the future — specifically, when the corresponding autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: And to answer the obvious follow-up of "Well, when is the corresponding autorelease pool drained?": In most cases, this will be the top-level autorelease pool that the AppKit/UIKit framework creates at the beginning of each run through the event loop and drains at the end.

Comment: @Chuck, @Bavarious, @Shaggy Frog thanks for the help with this and for the extra info about release v. autorelease and general programming conventions. I'm going to give it a try now. (Also, I'm totally impressed with the responses on this site and am looking forward to the day when I might actually contribute instead of just leech.)

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
return result;
[result release];
```

With:

```
return [result autorelease];
```